# Capturing javascript popups

Tags: c#, winforms

In WebBrowser, is there anyway to capture the stupid popups that are generated by javascript?

The ones which say "Success" or watever and have the "Ok" button.

I tried the WebBrowser "NewWindow" event, but this is not being fired.

Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply redefine the global javascript alert function like this:

```
function alert() {}
```

then nothing will happen when other code calls the alert.

UPDATE:

to do this add the following to your page code:

```
<script>
   function alert() {}
</script>
```

If you are injecting it to your pages then you may wish to look at greasemonkey and then add this script using that:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/

there are similar addons for all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I once needed to scrape a website using webbrowser where the site did all sorts of javascript I needed to bypass. My solution that time was to download the url with WebClient, parsing the html as a string and remove all javascript and then set the new html string as the Document of my WebBrowser.

Maybe that is a good approach for you?