# Captruing javascript popups

Tags: c#, javascript, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Capturing javascript popups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607747/capturing-javascript-popups)

Is there any way to capture java script popups opened from a webBrowser control? A webpage I am using signals success by opening a javascript popup. I don't need to know whats in it, just if it opened.

So:

Javascript opened ==> set bool to true.

Is this possible?

I already tried the WebBrowser.NewWindow event, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript alert boxes pause all JS execution while they are open, so you can't run anything in the background to determine this.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the window.opener from the pop-up window to get a reference to the main window, and you can set the value of a hidden variable in the parent window.

```
if (window.opener && !window.opener.closed)
    window.opener.document.formId.hdnPopupOpened.value = true;
```

As a side note, if you want more control of your popup, you can look into using dialogs (which are divs in the main page itself overlaid over contents). Check out jquery-ui for more information on dialogs.